# Check if internet is working or not in j2me

Tags: java, java-me, nokia

I am making application in j2me, i am sending data to server

but before that i want to first check that if internet is working or not (it may be from WIFI or GPRS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `getResponseCode()` and `getResponseMessage()` methods of `HttpConnection` API .

Answer (score 0):

There's no reliable way to determine if 'the internet is working' other than sending a request to your server. Just because you have a connection to an ISP, it doesn't mean that the ISP has a connection to the internet, or that a packet sent via that connection can reach your server.

The phone might tell you it's **not** connected, but if you want to know whether you can reach your server when it **is** connected, send a request and see what happens.